# Java/Tesseract-OCR: Unsatisfied LinkError libtesseract302

Tags: java, path, shared-libraries, classpath, tesseract

I'm migrating a coworkers Tesseract-OCR application from MacOSX to Windows 64 and running into issues with library paths.

When I execute an OCR process, I get this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract3
02': The specified module could not be found.
```

I have Tesseract 3.02.02 installed via the Windows installer:
    https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe&can=2&q=

I searched the installation folder and only found a libtesseract302.rc file sitting in the following path, and I don't think it's the right file anyway.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract-ocr\vs2008\libtesseract
```

System env variables:

```
TESSDATA_PREFIX = C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that setup installer only includes the .exe, data, and others but not the .dll that your program needs. You will need to download the source and [build](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/Compiling) it with the appropriate configuration. And since Tesseract is a 32-bit library, it will only work with Java 32-bit.